# How to hide and show title bar in black berry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

i want to hide title in the main screen and when objective choice field is selected i want to display title bar.Can any one please tell me how can i do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setTitle(null) to hide your title and when objective choice field is selected set it to your value.